# Show zero as hyphen in xtables

Tags: r, format, knitr, xtable

Say I have a knitr chunk such as this:

```
library(xtable)

<<>>=
x <- matrix(c(0, 1, 2, 0, 4, 5))
xtable(x)
@
```

Which yields the following LaTeX code (excerpt):

```
\hline
1 & 0,00 \\ 
2 & 1,00 \\ 
3 & 2,00 \\ 
4 & 0,00 \\ 
5 & 4,00 \\ 
6 & 5,00 \\ 
\hline
```

However, my actual table is larger (12 x 6) and has many zeros, which makes spotting non-zeros quite a task. I'd like to follow local table formatting guidelines, which recommend using hyphens for integer zeros (as opposed to zeros that result from approximation). In other words, I want my `xtable()` output to look like this:

```
\hline
1 & - \\ 
2 & 1,00 \\ 
3 & 2,00 \\ 
4 & - \\ 
5 & 4,00 \\ 
6 & 5,00 \\ 
\hline
```

How can I achieve this? I've looked into R `options` and knitr `opts_chunk` functions to no avail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't (otherwise) have missing data in the matrix/table, then you can use `xtable`'s ability to format `NA` to get the required result. Just change the 0's to `NA` and then use the `NA.string` option to `print.xtable`

```
tmp <- x
tmp[tmp==0] <- NA
print(xtable(tmp), NA.string = "-")
```

which gives

```tex
% latex table generated in R 3.0.1 by xtable 1.7-1 package
% Fri Sep 20 13:25:27 2013
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rr}
  \hline
 & x \\ 
  \hline
1 & - \\ 
  2 & 1.00 \\ 
  3 & 2.00 \\ 
  4 & - \\ 
  5 & 4.00 \\ 
  6 & 5.00 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

You could even wrap this in a function to isolate the mapping of 0 to NA from any other analysis and make it clear that this is for output formatting only.

```
xtable0dash <- function(x, ...) {
  x[x==0] <- NA
  print(xtable(x, ...), NA.string = "-")
}
```

Comment: In my case this does help, thanks for the tip! However, I must admit I'm resistant to attributing NA to my zeros, so I'll call this plan B for now. :)

Comment: That's why I copied `x` and modified the copy for display purposes. Wrap it in a function if you want to isolate it further (see the edit).

Comment: Mm, that is a good idea. Since this report is not long, I ended up doing your way and it was good enough for me. Thanks again!